# How to average similar tuples in an array of tuples in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, tuples

I really need your help. I have an array of tuples that looks like this:

```
[("07-21-2016", 5), ("07-21-2016", 1), ("07-21-2016", 2), ("07-21-2016", 3), ("07-21-2016", 4), ("07-21-2016", 5), ("07-20-2016", 6), ("07-20-2016", 5), ("07-19-2016", 5)]
```

I need to take all the tuples with the same date and average them out. So at the end it would look like:

```
[("07-21-2016", 33.3), ("07-20-2016", 5.5), ("07-19-2016", 5)]
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Sounds like you can sort the values into a dictionary of arrays and average them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let array = [("07-21-2016", 5), ("07-21-2016", 1), ("07-21-2016", 2), ("07-21-2016", 3), ("07-21-2016", 4), ("07-21-2016", 5), ("07-20-2016", 6), ("07-20-2016", 5), ("07-19-2016", 5)]

// Create dictionary to hold mapping of date to array of values    
var dict = [String: [Double]]()

// use forEach to add each value to the array for each key    
array.forEach {(date, num) in dict[date] = (dict[date] ?? []) + [Double(num)]}

// use map with reduce to find the average of each value and return a tuple
// containing the date and the average value    
let result = dict.map {(date, nums) in (date, nums.reduce(0, combine: +) / Double(nums.count))}

print(result)
```

Output:

> ```
> [("07-20-2016", 5.5), ("07-19-2016", 5.0), ("07-21-2016", 3.3333333333333335)]
> ```

---

#### Explanation:

```
array.forEach {(date, num) in dict[date] = (dict[date] ?? []) + [Double(num)]}
```

`forEach` takes each tuple of the array, looks up the array of values corresponding to `dict[date]` and appends the new `num` to that array.  If `dict[date]` returns `nil`, then this is the first time we've seen this key, so use the *nil coalescing operator* `??` to return an empty array `[]` and append the new value to that.

At the end of this, the contents of `dict` is:

> ```
> ["07-20-2016": [6.0, 5.0], "07-19-2016": [5.0], "07-21-2016": [5.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]]
> ```

```
let result = dict.map {(date, nums) in (date, nums.reduce(0, combine: +) / Double(nums.count))}
```

When `map` is applied to a dictionary, it takes each `(key, value)` pair and creates a new value based upon that.  The end result of `map` is a new array of the values it returns.  In this case, the value returned for each iteration of `map` is a tuple containing the `date` and the average of the numbers associated with that date.

```
nums.reduce(0, combine: +)
```

This sums the values in the nums array. `reduce` takes an initial value (`0` in this case) and a closure that will be evaluated for each value in the `nums` array.  Each iteration of `reduce` takes the current running total and the next value in `nums` and sums them.  This sum is then divided by `Double(nums.count)` to produce the average.  Finally, `map` returns `(date, avg)` which produces the final result.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way (using a dictionary to collate the numbers):

```
 let dateValues = [("07-21-2016", 5), ("07-21-2016", 1), ("07-21-2016", 2), ("07-21-2016", 3), ("07-21-2016", 4), ("07-21-2016", 5), ("07-20-2016", 6), ("07-20-2016", 5), ("07-19-2016", 5)]

 var averages:[String:(Int,Int)] = [:]
 for (date,value) in dateValues
 {
    averages[date] = averages[date] ?? (0,0)
    averages[date] = (averages[date]!.0 + value, averages[date]!.1 + 1)
 }
 let averagePerDate = averages.map{($0,Float($1.0)/Float($1.1))}.sort{$0.0>$1.0}

 print(averagePerDate) 

 // [("07-21-2016", 3.33333325), ("07-20-2016", 5.5), ("07-19-2016", 5.0)]
```

And a more concise one using sets:

```
 let dateList     = dateValues.reduce( Set<String>(), combine: { $0.union(Set([$1.0])) })
 let dateData     =   dateList.map{ date in return (date, dateValues.filter({$0.0==date}).map{$0.1}) }
 let dateCounts   =   dateData.map{ ($0, $1.reduce(0,combine:+), Float($1.count) ) }
 let dateAverages = dateCounts.map{ ($0, Float($1/$2) ) }.sort{$0.0>$1.0}

 print(dateAverages)
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I appreciate the help.